# System command fails in R Studio but works in R from Terminal

Tags: r, rstudio, system

I have a system command in R studio which fails whereas the same command works from R using Terminal in Mac. Could someone hint what is wrong here:

From RStudio:

```
> system('/bin/qt query -i /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmprObPeS/9c810678b567d9a52dec9a86/5.gz -v -d /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmprObPeS/94047c0ddd9fb36a892047be/0.phe.db -p "Phe=2" -g "count(UNKNOWN)<=0" -p "Phe=2" -g "HOM_ALT" > /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmprObPeS/9c810678b567d9a52dec9a86/out.vcf')
gqt: SQL error 'no such table: ped' in query 'SELECT BCF_ID FROM ped WHERE Phe=2 ORDER BY BCF_ID;': No such file or directory
```

The error message appears to have something to do with the tool but it also shows `No such file or directory` error whereas the same command works from terminal as shown below.

From R Terminal:

```
> system('/bin/qt query -i /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmprObPeS/9c810678b567d9a52dec9a86/5.gz -v -d /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmprObPeS/94047c0ddd9fb36a892047be/0.phe.db -p "Phe=2" -g "count(UNKNOWN)<=0" -p "Phe=2" -g "HOM_ALT" > /var/folders/z0/kms9x7hd6hgdtbtk3kxnjcjxw2_l57/T//RtmprObPeS/9c810678b567d9a52dec9a86/out.vcf')
```

The terminal command writes the output to the out.vcf file.

Comment: Does it work you open rstudio in super user mode?

Comment: I wonder how to open rstudio in super user mode? Does it mean from a user account with admin rights?

Comment: I think you'd need to show more code. You didn't make those auto-generated tempdir/tempfile strings by hand. You may not be aware that those files/paths _go away_ when an R session is closed so you can't rely on them for long-term operations.

Comment: The rStudio session which created the tmp files/paths is kept active and then the same command is run from R Terminal which works. So it means that the tmp files/paths are still available.  What sort of code is still required to be shown?

Comment: @chas sudo rstudio

Comment: it gives the error `sudo: rstudio: command not found` Does this explain the error and i need to have sudo rights? if not any other alternative?

Comment: the error seems to be coming while writing output to tmp file in tmp paths. Is it possible to change the tmp paths to real path?